# FInding relevant features for a time series segmentation

Tags: time-series, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I have a time series data, where each of the data point belongs to one of the known clusters. What I am interested is to perform a HMM so that we can obtain hidden states that further abstracts out the clusters.

Now for the HMM each observation i.e. data point is given as a feature vector where the features belongs to the properties of the cluster, for eg: the mean inter arrival time of the cluster, inter quartile range (shifting from third to 4th quartile) and lifetime of a clsuter (span).

Now what other features can be used for the task.
I am new to time series analysis.

My each data point is an image and is a social media post.

Comment: It is not clear what your data represents and what the meaning of the mentioned clusters and their properties is - you should add more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone  is thinking about the same question i.e what is an effective feature representation of a time series, they might look into the following two works

- [Highly comparative feature-based time-series
  classification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.3531.pdf)
- [Highly comparative time-series analysis: the empirical structure of time series and their methods](http://rsif.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royinterface/10/83/20130048.full.pdf)